# JMeter BeanShell PostProcessor Attempts to treat a String as byte[]

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

I have a `BeanShell` `PostProcessor` which starts with:

```
result = ctx.getPreviousResult();
String data = result.getResponseDataAsString();
```

On the second loop of a `LoopController`, it will give this in the log:

```
ERROR - jmeter.util.BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method: set    Variable assignment: data: Can't assign byte [] to java.lang.String 
WARN  - jmeter.extractor.BeanShellPostProcessor: Problem in BeanShell script org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: set    Variable assignment: data: Can't assign byte [] to java.lang.String
```

However, if I remove the `String` declaration, I do not get the warning (so using this to work around) ... i.e. be ambiguous about the type):

```
    data = result.getResponseDataAsString();
```

If I print `result.getResponseDataAsString().getClass().getName()` prior to this line, I get `java.lang.String`.

Fairly new to `BeanShell` use in JMeter, but pretty confident that line's the issue.

At the same time, if I have `log.info` statements prior to the `String data = ...` assignment, they will not print on the second loop iteration -- which makes me question that assessment.

How do I understand / correct the attempted `byte[]` assignment?

For reference: here is my test plan:

[image]

Basically, each sampler uses `result.getResponseDataAsString()` to get the response body, does some manipulation to "normalize" it and then sets a value via `vars.put()`.  The `BeanShell Assertion` uses `vars.get()` to retrieve the two values, compares them and the sets `FailureMessage` and `Failure` accordingly.

Note: both `PostProcessor`'s have the same issue.

Note 2:  `String data = new String( result.getResponseData() );` is equally problematic (i.e. same error) ... not that I would *ever* advocate for creating a `String` from a `byte[]` without being explicit about encoding / charset.

Comment: I tried your code, and did not get any error. Although you didn't need `ctx` for it, you could use `prev.getResponseDataAsString()` directly.
So either your response is really binary, or... Try this: create a BeanShell sampler with code: `SampleResult.setResponseData("Hello");` and put your post-processor under that sampler. Does it return the same error? If not, it means definitely something with your specific data. If yes, you need to look at your environment...

Comment: Thanks for the tip on `prev`.   Also, I used your BeanShell sampler idea to build the small .JMX mentioned in my answer.  You helpfully led me to discover my own mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created a small `.jmx` and successfully recreated the issue.

I tracked down to a specific line in JMeter Code (JMeter 3.0, `org.apache.jmeter.extractor.BeanShellPostProcessor:63`:

```
bshInterpreter.set("data", prev.getResponseData());//$NON-NLS-1$
```

That tipped me off ... I have a var named `data` in the above post-processor.

Looked again @ JMeter UI and ... sure enough, `data` is a pre-defined script var, typed (per above line) as a `byte[]`.

I'll assume that BeanShell managed the `byte[] <--> String`  casting when my var wasn't declared with `String`.  With the strict `String` declaration, type confusion was created.

Solved by renaming my script var to:

```
String localResponseData = result.getResponseDataAsString();
```

Lesson learned: don't name Bean Shell variables as `data` (or any other pre-defined one)!

Comment: Woow, great find :) I spent 30 min trying to figure out why my JMeter post process task can't use data variable name.

Comment: Of course, we could have both saved ourselves a lot of trouble by paying attention to the list of defined variable names on the UI :-\